# How to find the classes of the elements present inside the same div as a given element?

Tags: javascript

TLDR: Trying to find through JS which div a certain element is located in. If there are multiple nested list, I'd like to know classes of all of them.

My code is structured this way:

```
<div id="1">
  <button class="2"> ABC </button>
  <textarea class="3"> XYZ </textarea >
</div>
```

When button ABC is clicked, I find that an element with class 2 has been clicked. I'm trying to find:

1. Which div is this button located inside?
2. What other elements are located inside the same div?

Currently I'm finding the class of the clicked element using this code:

```
const wrapper = document.getElementById('1');

wrapper.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const isButton = event.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON';
  console.log("something was clicked00");
  if (!isButton) {
    console.log("it's not a button");
    return;
  })
```

This has helped me find which element is clicked in the first place.

But I couldn't find a way to find the points 1. and 2. I'm a beginner to JS, and any guidance is shighly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `.closest()` method to find the closest parent with a given ID and then use `.querySelectorAll()` to find all elements within the same div, like this:

```
wrapper.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const isButton = event.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON';
  console.log("something was clicked");
  if (!isButton) {
    console.log("it's not a button");
    return;
  }

  // find the closest parent div with id '1'
  const parentDiv = event.target.closest('#1');

  // find all elements inside the parent div
  const elements = parentDiv.querySelectorAll('*');

  // log the classes of all elements inside the parent div
  elements.forEach((element) => {
    console.log(element.classList);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Ashil! Didn't know about the closest() method. This helped a lot.